# CLI software to reliably send data

Tags: data-transfer

I have to reliably send data chunks from several computers (Linux and Windows) to a remote server (Linux).
Some computers send one 1000 bytes chunk each hour, others send ten 50 bytes chunks per minute, etc.
I need to make this work across reboots, network disruptions, etc. So the sending side has to store data to the disk until sent and acknowledged.

Which kind of solution can I use?

I currently use a MTA (Mail Transfert Agent): works on Linux+Windows, easy to interface with the data producer softwares, reliable (it connects directly to the receiving server), encrypted, authenticated, travel thought nazzi-firewalls.
Works well but is overkill in term of network and CPU/RAM load.

Another way could be to use a private P2P software. When a new data chunk is available, it is stored as a file, then sent. I'm not sure how to know when a data chunk is sent, in order to delete it locally.

Or FTP/SMB/etc with a batch runing in loop?

--> Does this kind of thing has a name? Easier for a search engines.
--> What whould you recommand?

Answer (score 2):

You can use syncthing sync.

https://syncthing.net/

It is possible do use it as one way sync, which is basically uploading.

It resumes automaticaly and it is lightweight (20 - 40 MB of RAM) and reliable.

It is cli application with optional web interface.